# SwiftUI: How to update button state from view model

Tags: button, mvvm, swiftui, state, viewmodel

I want to enable and disable another button by updating the state variable in my view model. However, the other button is not activated. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var viewModel = ViewModel()


var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.enableButton()
        }){
            Text("Activate other button")
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            /// code
        }){
            Text("To be activated...")
        }.disabled(viewModel.buttonDisabled)
    }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @State var buttonDisabled = true

    func enableButton() {
       buttonDisabled = false
    }

}
```

Comment: `@State` only works inside a `SwiftUI.View` not a `class`. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) you seems to be early on in your coding journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small mistake. You are supposed to use `@Published` in your view model and `@ObservedObject` in your view.

Modified code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel() //modified

var body: some View {
VStack {
    Button(action: {
        viewModel.enableButton()
    }){
        Text("Activate other button")
    }
    
    Button(action: {
        /// code
    }){
        Text("To be activated...")
    }.disabled(viewModel.buttonDisabled)
}
}
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var buttonDisabled = true //modified

func enableButton() {
   buttonDisabled = false
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a `State`, but `StateObject`, because your `ViewModel` is a `ObservableObject` class

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()  // << here !!

// ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly !! Can u explain why?

Comment: @Jonas, small question, how did it work when you had @ State in your view model?

Comment: It didn't work :( The var in viewModel was updated but my view was not updated, so the button stayed disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change class to struct, e.g.

```
struct Content {
    var buttonDisabled = true

    mutating func enableButton() {
       buttonDisabled = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var content = Content()
...
```